# Multiple user types

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm looking at creating 3 groups for my application:

`Company`
`Department`
`Staff`

So a `Company` can have many `Departments` and each can have many `Staff`

Currently I have a `User` entity and I'm using roles to log a User in.

Architecturally, which is a good approach to do this?

Could I simply have a `User` and then extend for the `Company` and the `Department` and `Staff`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can easily do that using one-to-many relationship

Comment: So have a `Company` entity with a $user field that is one-to-many?

Comment: yes, you will have 4 entity (User, Company, Department and Staff)